# How do I make a copy of one directory files(hidden files included) into another directory?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm trying to make a copy of one directory files into another directory.

I have Desktop/projectOne and Desktop/projectTwo and I'm trying to copy projectOne files into projectTwo. I need to use terminal for this as I need to copy hidden files also and I'm not familiar with linux commands...

So my question is...

1. What commands do I have to use to copy all files (hidden files included) from Desktop/projectOne to Desktop/projectTwo?
2. What commands do I have to use to copy only hidden files from Desktop/projectOne to Desktop/projectTwo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is appropriate for [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/). That said `cp` is used to copy files. `cd Desktop/projectOne` and then `cp -a * ../projectTwo` to copy regular files and then `cp -a .* ../projectTwo` to copy hidden (dot) files. Or with `rsync` installed, simply `rsync -ua Desktop/projectOne/ Desktop/projectTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

cp -r

Example: cp -r /oldfolder /home/newfolder

Noticed: if newfolder is already exist it will create new folder in it
/home/newfolder/oldfolder